# Failed to build CUDA kernels for upfirdn2d on Google colab

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am trying to experiment with a Deep learning framework called [STIT(Stitch in Real Time)](https://github.com/rotemtzaban/STIT), and it needs CUDA too. As I googled and found on Stackoverflow that you need to put run time on GPU in the case of google Colab and so I did. However, I get the error message

```
warnings.warn('Failed to build CUDA kernels for upfirdn2d. Falling back to slow reference implementation. Details:\n\n' + traceback.format_exc())
100% 98/98 [00:45<00:00,  2.13it/s]
```

Which results in really slow training.
Any suggestions, What should I do here?

[image]

Comment: here is a copy of the notebook

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Rbfb7wyKA5DVd3LyBCWhT9WyPH_b2xDd?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

ok, I don't know why but the installation of the following solved the problem

```
!wget https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases/download/v1.8.2/ninja-linux.zip
!sudo unzip ninja-linux.zip -d /usr/local/bin/
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ninja ninja /usr/local/bin/ninja 1 --force
```

An explanation around it is appreciated